# Error in cropping the image using binary mask

Tags: python, opencv, mask, image-segmentation, masking

I would like to crop my original image using the binary mask for which I have written code

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import matplotlib as plt

img = cv2.imread("image.png")
mask = cv2.imread("mask.png")
h, w, _ = img.shape
mask = cv2.resize(cv2.cvtColor(mask, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY), (w, h)) # Resize image
bg = np.zeros_like(img, 'uint8') # Black background
def crop(img, bg, mask):
 fg = cv2.bitwise_or(img, img, mask=mask) 
 fg_back_inv = cv2.bitwise_or(bg, bg, mask=cv2.bitwise_not(mask))
 New_image = cv2.bitwise_or(fg, fg_back_inv)
 return New_image

plt.imshow(cv2.cvtColor(New_image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB))
```

I am getting an error which states

```
NameError: name 'New_image' is not defined
```

Kindly suggest me where i am making a mistake here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have only created the function *crop*, but you haven't called it. You will have to create the variable and assign the value you get from the function, and only then use it for the plot.

```
def crop(img, bg, mask):
 fg = cv2.bitwise_or(img, img, mask=mask) 
 fg_back_inv = cv2.bitwise_or(bg, bg, mask=cv2.bitwise_not(mask))
 New_image = cv2.bitwise_or(fg, fg_back_inv)
 return New_image
New_image = crop(img, bg, mask)
plt.imshow(cv2.cvtColor(New_image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB))
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use the function, and maybe assign the return value to `New_image` variable:

```py
import cv2
import numpy as np
import matplotlib as plt

img = cv2.imread("image.png")
mask = cv2.imread("mask.png")
h, w, _ = img.shape
mask = cv2.resize(cv2.cvtColor(mask, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY), (w, h)) # Resize image
bg = np.zeros_like(img, 'uint8') # Black background
def crop(img, bg, mask):
 fg = cv2.bitwise_or(img, img, mask=mask) 
 fg_back_inv = cv2.bitwise_or(bg, bg, mask=cv2.bitwise_not(mask))
 New_image = cv2.bitwise_or(fg, fg_back_inv)
 return New_image

New_image = crop(img,bg,mask)        #   <--------------
plt.imshow(cv2.cvtColor(New_image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB))
```

Or you could do this, without the `New_image` variable:

```py
plt.imshow(cv2.cvtColor(crop(img,bg,mask), cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
```